# Which Delegate method trigger on click Dont't Allow for CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, cllocationmanager

Using `CLLocationManager` It show pop up message

with Allow "AppName" to access your location even when you are not using the app?

with two options **Don't Allow** and **Allow**  On click Allow it triggers `didUpdateLocations`  When click **Don't Allow** what is the delegate method it calls?

Answer (score 2):

if user deny the permission `didFailWithError` has called and error type also

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

   // [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"error%@",error);
    switch([error code])
{
    case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Error!" message:@"Can't access your current location! Please check your network connection or that you are not in airplane mode!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
        break;
    case kCLErrorDenied:{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Error!" message:@"Location Access has been denied for app name!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        // alert.tag=500;
        [alert show];

    }
        break;
    default:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Error!" message:@"Can't access your current location!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
        break;
}



 }
```